# Html no preloading

Tags: javascript, html, image, preload

I have to use some gallery with JQuery (I'm using Galleria). The problem is that the structure is like:

```
<div id="galleria">
   <img src="(...).jpg" />
   <img src="(...).jpg" />
   <img src="(...).jpg" />
   <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The plugin takes all photos from that list and use them. The problem: I have a lot of high-quality photos. And all they are preloaded before plugin can use them. Are there any ways to load images dynamically? (Maybe, some new gallery plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where [jQuery LazyLoad plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) comes in handy :)

> Lazy loader is a jQuery plugin written
>   in JavaScript. It delays loading of
>   images in (long) web pages. Images
>   outside of viewport (visible part of
>   web page) wont be loaded before user
>   scrolls to them. This is opposite of
>   image preloading.
>
> Using lazy load on long web pages
>   containing many large images makes the
>   page load faster. Browser will be in
>   ready state after loading visible
>   images. In some cases it can also help
>   to reduce server load.

[Demo Page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html)